# PayPal subscription payment is not working with sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have used the following code for PayPal subscribe button, from the sandbox.paypal.com:-

---

```
 <div id="paypal-button-container-P-86B16126YE351481NMH6WMRY"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AT4fx8CxfLze4ZzMRrp-yUZBlKQvFt97cMDgzUwqXBpbvPSw7w0EmoLBk1zJw7PddEDRD_HJ05y4qjh5&vault=true&intent=subscription" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'pill',
            color: 'silver',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            label: 'subscribe'
        },
        createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                /* Creates the subscription */
                plan_id: 'P-86B16126YE351481NMH6WMRY'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container-P-86B16126YE351481NMH6WMRY'); // Renders the PayPal button
</script>
```

---

But, when clicking this button from the website (where I put this button code) and logging into the PayPal sandbox for the payment, it shows the following error message:-

---

Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you selected. Please try another payment method.

---

I have tried all the available payment methods for my sandbox account(where from I am trying to subscribe). But nothing worked. I have been trying it for the last couple of hours, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Review your list of [sandbox accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts), log into this button's account via [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) and go to its [email settings](https://www.sanbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email).  Resend a confirmation "email" if necessary--sandbox doesn't send real email messages.

Read the confirmation "email" in the "Notifications" side tab of the [developer dashboard](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications), and use the link there to confirm it.

Retry your subscription payment after having confirmed the receiving sandbox account's primary email.